# Disable uploading javascript files with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any way to block uploading JavaScript files into specific folder using htaccess but still allow running JavaScript in sub-folders?

Comment: How is the uploading done? Block it there.

Comment: FTP has nothing to do with .htaccess. Also javascript runs within the client, not the server, so the only thing you can do is blocking the access to some .js files... but why?! Please tell us what you want to achieve... this is very unclear atm.

Comment: a hack is injecting a javascipt in the root folder ( public_html) and runs it from the browser.. and as a quick solution i want to dsable javascript from root folder .. hope this makes sense

Comment: that doesn´t make sense, sorry ;) if you have been hacked, deleted all files on the webserver and reupload them from your local backup!

Comment: As suggested by Tobiask, the better way is to include the following code in your .htaccess file: <Files ~ "\.js$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>